# removing character from string value in dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, integer

I hope you can help me with this question. I have a column with numeric values as strings. Since they are data from diferent countries, some of them have different formats such as "," and "$". I'm trying to convert the serie to numbers, but i'm having trouble with "," and "$" values.

```
data={"valores":[1,1,3,"4","5.00","1,000","$5,700"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    valores
0   1
1   1
2   3
3   4
4   5.00
5   1,000
6   $5,700
```

Ive tried the following:

```
df["valores"].replace(",","")
```

but it does not change a thing since the "," value is in the string, not the string value itself

```
pd.to_numeric(df["valores"])
```

But I receive the "ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,000" at position 5" error.

```
valores=[i.replace(",","") for i in df["valores"].values]
```

But I receive the "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace' error.

So, at last, I tried with this:

```
valores=[i.replace(",","") for i in df["valores"].values if type(i)==str]
valores
['4', '5.00', '1000', '$5700']
```

But it skipped the first three values since they are not strings..

I think that with a Regex code i would be able to manage it, but I just simply dont understand how to work with it.

I hope you can help me since i've been struggling with this for about 7 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a string from it, so something like this

```
valores=[str(i).replace(",","") for i in df["valores"].values]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['valores'] = df['valores'].replace(to_replace='[\,\$]',value='',regex=True).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` by default searches for the **whole cell values**. Since you want to replace a part of the string, you need `.str.replace` or `replace(...,regex=True)`:

```
df['valores'] = df["valores"].replace(",","", regex=True)
```

Or:

```
df['valore'] = df["valores"].str.replace(",","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the values in the `valores` column to string using `.astype(str)`, then remove all `$` and `,` using `.str.replace('[,$]', '')` and then you may convert all data to numeric using `pd.to_numeric`:

```py
>>> pd.to_numeric(df["valores"].astype(str).str.replace("[,$]",""))
0       1.0
1       1.0
2       3.0
3       4.0
4       5.0
5    1000.0
6    5700.0
```